# How to get an array of unique values of a specific key provided I only have an array of id's of that object using ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have a store set up for a list of candidate objects like this

```
const candidatesStore = [
   { id: 1, status: active}
   {id:2, status: inactive}
   {id: 3 status: failed}
   {id: 4 status:inactive}
   {id: 5 status:failed}

    .
    ... and so on ]
```

I only have the list of id's in an array, `ex: requiredArray = [2,3,4]`

How to get a list of unique statuses by just using `requiredArray` using ES6 in the most efficient way

The result should be `[inactive, failed]` 
I preferably want to use `reduce` to get unique value, and `find` to get the list of `candidates` from `candidatesStore`

Comment: What's going on with these `candidate1 =` assignments in your array literal?

Comment: How about `Array.from(new Set(candidatesStore.filter(cand => requiredArray.includes(cand.id)).map(cand => cand.status)))`? I don't see how `reduce` or `find` could be useful here.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "reduce" as well as "filter" for this.

Note - I have to change your input object little bit as "candidate1 = ..." was not making much sense here.

```js
const candidates = [
    {id: 1, status: 'active'}
    ,{id: 2, status: 'inactive'}
    ,{id: 3, status: 'failed'}
    ,{id: 4, status: 'inactive'}
    ,{id: 5, status: 'failed'}
]

const requiredArray = [2,3,4]

let result = [...candidates.filter(({ id }) =>  requiredArray.includes(id))
                           .reduce((s, d) => s.add(d.status) , new Set)
             ]

console.log(result)
```

Comment: FWIW, you can also skip the `.map` step and do `.reduce((s, d) => s.add(d.status) , new Set)`

Comment: Yeah Correct. Thank you for pointing Sir!! BTW been long time follower of your detailed answers, which has helped me understand JS better. Want to take this chance to Thank you for spreading knowledge!! 

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
const candidates = [
    {id: 1, status: "active"},
    {id: 2, status: "inactive"},
    {id: 3, status: "failed"},
    {id: 4, status: "inactive"},
    {id: 5, status: "failed"},
];
let requiredArray = [2,3,4];
let newArray = candidates.filter(x=>requiredArray.includes(x.id))
console.log(newArray);
```